# Regex in c++ for maching some patters

Tags: c++, regex, lexical-analysis

I want regex of this.

- add x2, x1, x0 is a valid instruction;

I want to implement this. But bit confused, how to, as I am newbie in using Regex. Can anyone share these Regex?

Comment: I am not sure that regex is the right approach

Comment: You can reasonably parse `G0` and `G3` with regex, but `G1` and `G2` would make the regex quite large and unwieldy and that part of parsing would be better done after the initial parse.

Comment: @pm100 can you suggest any other approach?

Comment: @Nick yes this will be a large regex. Can you help me with the G0 and G3 regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a longer project and will have more requirements later, then definitely a different approach would be better.

The standard approach to solve such a problem ist to define a grammar and then created a lexer and a parser. The tools lex/yacc or flex/bison can be used for that. Or, a simple shift/reduce parser can also be hand crafted.

The language that you sketched with the given grammar, may be indeed specified with a Chomsky class 3 grammar, and can hence be produced gy a regular grammar. And, with that, parsed with regular expressions.

The specification is a little bit unclear as to what a register is and if there are more keyowrds. Especially ecall is unclear.

But how to build such a regex?

You will define small tokens and concatenate them. And different paths can be implemented with the or operator `|`.

Let's give sume example.

- a register may be matched with `a\d+`. So, an "a" followed by ome digits. If it is not only "a", but other letters as well, you could use `[a-z]\d+`
- op codes with the same number of parameters can be listed up with a simple or `|`. like in `add|sub`
- For spaces there are many solutions. you may use `\s+` or `[ ]+`or whatever spaces you need.
- To build one rule, you can concatenate what you learned so far
- Having different parts needs an or `|` for the complete path
- If you want to get back the matched groups, you must enclose the needed stuff in brackets

And with that, one of many many possible solutions can be:

```
^[ ]*((add|sub)[ ]+(a\d+)[ ]*,[ ]*(a\d+)[ ]*,[ ]*(a\d+)|(ecall))[ ]*$
```

See example in: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hp3cOl/1)